# In a fish shell function how to pipe stdin to a variable?

Tags: function, fish

Here's what I got:

```
function stdin2var
    set a (cat -)
    echo $a
end
```

First example:

```
$ echo 'some text' | stdin2var
# should output "some text"
```

Second example:

```
$ echo some text\nsome more text | stdin2var
# should output: "some text
some more text"
```

Any tips?

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted my question. I'd be happy to edit it if there is something to be improved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fish shell (and others), you want `read`:

```
echo 'some text' | read varname
```

Comment: if the pipe has newline separated content, only the first line is kept. What am I missing?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish, I don't understand why `set a (cat -)` does not consume the function's stdin. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's because fish doesn't propagate block redirections into command substitutions. Perhaps it should.

Comment: Use `read -z` for null terminated, multi-line input (basically whatever you pipe through)

Answer (score 6):

Following up on @ridiculous_fish's answer, use a while loop to consume all input:

```
function stdin2var
    set -l a
    while read line
        set a $a $line
    end
    # $a is a *list*, so use printf to output it exactly.
    echo (count $a)
    printf "%s\n"  $a
end
```

So you get

```
$ echo foo bar | stdin2var
1
foo bar

$ seq 10 | stdin2var
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: The annoying thing, which is not a fault of your answer but rather of Fish, is that if nothing is piped through stdin, the while read command will wait for the user to input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store stdin into a scalar variable:

```sh
function stdin2var
    read -l -z a

    set --show a
    echo $a
end

echo some text\nsome more text | stdin2var
# $a: set in local scope, unexported, with 1 elements
# $a[1]: length=25 value=|some text\nsome more text\n|
# some text
# some more text
```

If you want to split lines in to a array:

```sh
function stdin2var
    set -l a
    IFS=\n read -az a

    set --show a
    for line in $a
        echo $line
    end
end

echo some text\nsome more text | stdin2var
# $a: set in local scope, unexported, with 2 elements
# $a[1]: length=9 value=|some text|
# $a[2]: length=14 value=|some more text|
# some text
# some more text
```